# Google maps - Update User location

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google maps SDK for iOS. 
The `isMyLocationEnabled` is set to `true`.

Sometimes the use location updated to the right location. But sometimes the location is not updated.
I wanted to know if this option is using the original coordinates of the user? also, there is an option to update the user location? ) I am talking about the blue point.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class Location: NSObject {

  static let shared = Location()
  var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  func locationManagerSetup() {
    // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    // If location services is enabled get the users location
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
      locationManager.delegate = self
      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
      locationManager.requestLocation()
      locationManager.startUpdatigLocation()
    }

  }

}

extension Location: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
      // do something
      manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else {
      manager.requestLocation()
    }
  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    manager.requestLocation()
  }

  // If we have been deined access give the user the option to change it
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if(status == CLAuthorizationStatus.denied) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```